# Windows Phone 7 Designer: How to resolve 'System.InvalidProgramException' error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I've just started developing with Windows Phone. At the very first launch of the IDE I am seeing the following error where there should be a designer. How can this be resolved?

[image: Error on home scren]
Zoomed:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the full callstack  ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occured because of the version of silverlight installed in my system. The necessary version of sliverlight is the [silverlight developer edition.](http://silverlight.dlservice.microsoft.com/download/D/C/2/DC2D5838-9138-4D25-AA92-52F61F7C51E6/runtime/Silverlight_Developer.exe) After uninstalling  installed version and replacing it with the above, I was able to get the designer to show.